# Can't Titan Black use NVENC?

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia

I compiled FFMPEG with --enable-nvenc and want to encode with NVENC encoder, but I got this error message when running ffmpeg.

```
[nvenc_h264 @ 0x8ed020] 4 CUDA capable devices found
[nvenc_h264 @ 0x8ed020] [ GPU #0 - < GeForce GTX TITAN Black > has Compute SM 3.5, NVENC Not Available ]
[nvenc_h264 @ 0x8ed020] [ GPU #1 - < GeForce GTX TITAN Black > has Compute SM 3.5, NVENC Not Available ]
[nvenc_h264 @ 0x8ed020] [ GPU #2 - < GeForce GTX TITAN Black > has Compute SM 3.5, NVENC Not Available ]
[nvenc_h264 @ 0x8ed020] [ GPU #3 - < GeForce GTX TITAN Black > has Compute SM 3.5, NVENC Not Available ]
[nvenc_h264 @ 0x8ed020] No NVENC capable devices found
```

I have titan black gpu and as the official document said it should be supported.

my nvenc-sdk version is 5.0

and the nvidia-smi info is listed below.

```
~> nvidia-smi
Wed Jan  6 16:36:55 2016
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.39     Driver Version: 352.39         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 54%   82C    P2   215W / 250W |   4422MiB /  6143MiB |     77%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 55%   82C    P2   160W / 250W |   5926MiB /  6143MiB |     84%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 58%   83C    P2   147W / 250W |   5926MiB /  6143MiB |     68%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:84:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 53%   83C    P2   191W / 250W |   3155MiB /  6143MiB |     85%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't comment on your answer because of low rep, but for anyone who comes across this later I'll try to save you the time and tell you that the ffmpeg flag you're looking for is -pix_fmt yuv420p.

This would make the whole command something resembling this:

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vcodec nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer.

ffmpeg will check the GPU capability for encoding.

and there is an threshold:

```
target_smver = avctx->pix_fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P ? 0x52 : 0x30;
```

Titan Black have smver 3.5, it can only encode YUV420P pix format video.